# Multi form submit with one selector use jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with jquery ajax multi form. 
every execution is always part of the form at the top, to form the other does not work.
can help me.
this Source Code

```
<form id="form_action" action="http://www.dom.dom/act/">
<input type="text" name="nama" value="" />
<button type="submit" >Save</buton>
</form>
<form id="form_action" action="http://www.dom.dom/act/">
<input type="text" name="nama" value="" />
<button type="submit" >Save</buton>
</form>
<form id="form_action" action="http://www.dom.dom/act/">
<input type="text" name="nama" value="" />
<button type="submit" >Save</buton>
</form>
<form id="form_action" action="http://www.dom.dom/act/">
<input type="text" name="nama" value="" />
<button type="submit" >Save</buton>
</form>
jquery ajax nya :
$("‪#‎form_action‬").on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var link = $(this).attr("action");
var data = $(this).serialize();
$.ajajx({
url:link,
data:data,
type:"POST",
typeData:'html',
cache:false,
success: function(data){
//// bla bla //
}
});
return false;
});
```

How to use this jquery for multi form..?

Comment: ok, first thing before I go crazy, please use classes if you want multiple elements with the same name, that might even fix your problem.  Make sure to change the jquery to be .form_action

Comment: also, can you make a jsfiddle to show us the problem in action?

Comment: Also, `$.ajajx` is probably causing some issues

Answer (score 0):

When you use an id selector (`$('#some-id')`) you get only the first element that matches your selector, not an array as you get with other selectors.
Also, it seems that they're all the same form.. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you can use the same form and just change `action` attribute or some input in the form.
Another thing, as @dave mentioned in the comments, there's no `$.ajajx` function in jQuery :-)